# Updating UI when XML changes

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I have a UI in a window, which is bound to an XML file. I need to update the UI whenever I manually go and change my XML file.

Following is the [WAML](http://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/WAML-XPlore-Web-Application-Markup-Language-Alfega-Technologies-Inc) file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="dataSource" Source="Data/Media.xml">
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Name="listBox1" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataSource}, XPath=/Media/Book/@Title, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The following is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Media>
    <Book Author='John' Title='Fish are my aaaa friends' />
    <Book Author='Dave' Title='Fish are my enemies' />
    <Book Author='Jane' Title='Fish are my food' />
</Media>
```

I have a window object in the service layer. To initialise it, I did the following:

`winobj.DataContext = node.OuterXml; winobj.Show();` where `node` is my XML string which I get from the server. If I ask you to update this winobj or reset its datacontext so that the UI is updated, how will you do it?

My UI is bound in the following way.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" XPath="//WindowUpdate" />
</Window.Resources>
<Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data},
       XPath=Window/Children/Label[@id\=\'lblInterval\']/@text}" ...
```

Comment: That's some inventive sample data.  What were you thinking at the time?

Comment: Hey Kieren...:)....this data comes from the book essential wpf, databinding chapter.....please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to catch changes to the file, how you change the data is up to you (e.g. expose a [bindable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) property and change that).

Comment: Hey H.B....thanks for the reply. But i eventually want to achieve a finance application similar to the one which displays changing stock prices and updates the UI. I have a background thread which does an asynchronous read and has a reference to the window object. The thread is reading the data fine but i am not able to update the UI. If possible please help on that front as well.

Comment: @Kunal: Why are you not able to update the UI? How did you try to do it? How did not work? What did you expect? Please provide more information to give the problem some bounds.

Comment: Hey H.B. ...I have a window object with me in service layer, to initialise it, i did the following :-  winobj.DataContext = node.OuterXml;
                winobj.Show();

Comment: Hey H.B. ...I have a window object in service layer, to initialise it, i did the following :-    winobj.DataContext = node.OuterXml;
winobj.Show(); where node is my xml string which i get from server. If i ask you to update this winobj or reset it's datacontext so that the UI is updated, how will you do it?? My UI is bound in the following way :- <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Data" XPath="//WindowUpdate"  />
    </Window.Resources>
        <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data},  XPath=Window/Children/Label[@id\=\'lblInterval\']/@text}" ...

Comment: I am sorry, did not read ur comment...kindly tell me what to do...as this is the first time i am posting here

Comment: @Kunal: Edit things like that into your question, but please avoid changing what a question is about, we do not want questions morph it into something else or turn into debugging sessions.